# Regex expression to remove HTML but with exceptions

Tags: c#, html, regex

In C#, I have the following regex expression to remove HTML from a string:

```
var regex = new Regex("<[^>]*(>|$)");
return regex.Replace(input, match => "");
```

There are some cases where we need to allow for double `>>` and `<<`. 
How do I change the above expression to simply skip these double angled brackets?

Comment: by "remove HTML" you mean to strip the tags and get just text?

Comment: @Aziz, I updated the code above. The regex removes the HTML, but it chokes on >> and <<. I like the expression to just ignore these double angle brackets. In fact, they are C++ code snippets.

Comment: Sigh... regex is the wrong tool for dealing with XML or HTML.  What's going to happen when a tag is broken across multiple lines?

Comment: Mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4037348

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of the link (don't use Regex for HTML parsing), but our scenario is simple and controlled.

Comment: @JimGarrison since when does regex care about lines unless specifically told to care about lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the $ at the end is in there too, but anyway... [negative lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can solve this problem:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<![<])<[^<>]+>(?![>])");
return regex.Replace(input, String.Empty);
```

This will match any < not preceded by another <, then the content, and then any > not followed by another >.